# why does my guessing game skip over the 'lower' and 'higher' parts

Tags: python

```py
import random
import time
numOfGuesses = 0
guess = ''
playername = ''
numbertoguess = 0
MAX_GUESS = 10
#======================
playername = input ('What is your name:')
numbertoguess = random.randint (1, 100)
input("hello, " + playername + ", Guess the number I am thinking of (hint: its between 1 and 100")
#======================
while numOfGuesses < MAX_GUESS:
     guess = int(input("What is your guess:"))
     numOfGuesses += 1
     time.sleep(1)
if guess < numbertoguess:
     print ('Higher')
if guess > numbertoguess:
     print ('Lower')
elif numOfGuesses > MAX_GUESS:
     sys.exit()
else:
     sys.exit()
     #======================
     if guess == numbertoguess:
          print ("You are right," + playername + ",you guessed it in " + str(numOfGuesses) + "tries")
     elif guess != numbertoguess and numOfGuesses == 10:
          print ("awe so close," + playername + ".")
          print ("the number was" + str(numbertoguess) +".")
```

when you finish one guess instead of telling you to go "higher" or "lower" the code runs over them and doesn't print either. I'm so new to python if someone could help me that would be great.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Most of the code needs to be inside the `while numOfGuesses < MAX_GUESS:` loop.

Comment: `elif numOfGuesses > MAX_GUESS:` can never be true because of the `while` condition.

Comment: You need `elif guess > numbertoguess:`, not just `if`. Otherwise, the last `else:` is just connected to this `if`, so it will be executed when `guess < numbertoguess`

Comment: That `else` block means you exit the script when the guess is correct, so you'll never get to the code that says you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a few problems here.

**1)** Python treats newlines as semicolons in C-like languages, so

```
input("hello, " + playername + ", Guess the number I am thinking of   
(hint     its     between 1 and 100")
```

will throw a syntax error.  To encode a newline, use the escape sequence `"\n"`

```
input("hello, " + playername + ", Guess the number I am thinking of \n(hint it's between 1 and 100")
```

This looks like a copy + paste issue though.

**2)** Python uses indentations to figure out where your blocks are.  So all of the statements in your loop body **MUST** begin with the same number of spaces / tabs as the rest.  So your while loop should look like (indentation wise)

```
while numOfGuesses < MAX_GUESS:
    guess = int(input("What is your guess:"))
    numOfGuesses += 1
    time.sleep(1)

    if guess < numbertoguess:
        print ('Higher')
    if guess > numbertoguess:
        print ('Lower')
    elif numOfGuesses > MAX_GUESS:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        sys.exit()
```

I believe this is causing the issues you specified in your question title.  Since the while loop is only executing the line `guess = int(input("What is your guess:"))` because it is the only one indented properly.

Note: you cannot mix tabs and spaces, python will have a fit and [no soup for you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOpfsGrNvnk)

Also indentation styles are typically 4 spaces or 1 tab.  Single space indents WILL give you headaches after a while.

**3)** If you need a delay, the proper function is `time.sleep()`

**4)** You have two if statements in your while body, so should the guess pass the `if guess < numbertoguess:` it will continue to the next `if guess > numbertoguess:` and fail it. Then it will jump to the `else` body, which is a system exit / break statement.  Either will cause the game to end prematurely.

Change if chain to:

```
if guess < numbertoguess:
    print ('Higher')
elif guess > numbertoguess:
    print ('Lower')
elif numOfGuesses > MAX_GUESS:
    break;
else:
    break;
```

**5)** You have `sys.exit()` but you forgot to `import sys`.  Also `exit()` does not need to be imported, you can use it without the `sys` module.

**6)** `exit()` quits your program.  Nothing after the while loop will run if one of those `elif / else` statements executes.  The statement you are looking for is likely the `break` statement, which continues program execution on the next line after the loop.

**7)** Same as number 1), you've got a statement split across two lines here

```
print ("You are right," + playername + ",you guessed it in "+str  
(numOfGuesses) + "tries")
```

Fix to

```
print ("You are right," + playername + ",you guessed it in " + str(numOfGuesses) + "tries")
```

**NOTES**

Style wise, use 4 space or 1 tab indentations.  It makes things easier to read.  Also use newlines to separate logical blocks in code.  You can use `#===========` to denote important blocks or *huge* logical blocks.

That's not to say you cannot have no newlines and cannot use `#===========` for logical blocks, but people reading your code will hate you.

---

Your strings are missing some formatting here and there

---

You've hardcoded the max guesses here at the bottom: `elif guess != numbertoguess and numOfGuesses == 10:`  In fact, you don't really need that check, since you've checked for a correct answer above.

```
if guess == numbertoguess:
    print ("You are right," + playername + ",you guessed it in " + str(numOfGuesses) + "tries")

else:    
    print ("awe so close," + playername + ".")
    print ("the number was" + str(numbertoguess) +".")
```

This works because there are two logical states that the user can be in at the moment: guessed correctly or guessed incorrectly `MAX_GUESS` times.  Should you have 3+ logical states (guessed correctly, guessed incorrectly, guessed 42 for an easter egg), you will have to have another check.

---

Consider using a for loop instead of a while loop.  `while` loops are good for when you do not need to know how many loops you've done, or when your loop criteria is a specific boolean expression. (ex `while something.hasNext():`)

`for` loops are good for a specific number of iterations, or when you need to access something sequentially.  (there are also for each loops).

```
for i in range(MAX_GUESS): # i = 0 to i = MAX_GUESS -1
```

Then you won't need a check for your number of guesses since you're guaranteed to loop a max of MAX_GUESS times

---

A suggestion if I may.  Get an IDE (integrated Development Environment) with syntax highlighting and checking.  I use [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/) with a [python](http://www.pydev.org/) plugin, but eclipse is a bit much for beginners.  Our CS professors suggested [Wing](https://wingware.com/), but I never used it

### ---

Finished product (aside from string formatting.  I'll let you do that):

```
import random
import time

numOfGuesses   = 0
numbertoguess  = 0
MAX_GUESS      = 10
guess          = ''
playername     = ''

playername = input ('What is your name:')
numbertoguess = random.randint (1, 100)
input("hello, " + playername + ", Guess the number I am thinking of \n(hint it's between 1 and 100")

for numOfGuesses in range(MAX_GUESS): # nOG = 0 to nOG = MAX_GUESS -1
    guess = int(input("What is your guess:"))
    time.sleep(1)

    if guess < numbertoguess:
        print ('Higher')
    elif guess > numbertoguess:
        print ('Lower')
    else:
        break;

if guess == numbertoguess:
    print ("You are right," + playername + ",you guessed it in " + str(numOfGuesses) + "tries")

else:    
    print ("awe so close," + playername + ".")
    print ("the number was" + str(numbertoguess) +".")
```